'com.provider.fatoria.model.ConfigPergunta' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)
I have a problem because my table has a self relationship. I have to be able to insert and change the column, but it always gives this error: Column 'idTipoDoctoEntrada' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.provider.fatoria.model.ConfigPergunta' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false) 'when mapping multiple properties to the same column). I can't do it this way, because I need to be able to change and insert.
ConfigPerguntaPk :
@Embeddable
public class ConfigPerguntaPk {
    
    private Long idConfigPergunta;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idTipoDoctoEntrada")
    private TipoDoctoEntrada tipoDoctoEntrada;

ConfigPergunta :
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbConfigPergunta")
@DynamicUpdate
public class ConfigPergunta {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ConfigPerguntaPk configPerguntaPk;
    
    private String txPergunta;
    private String txAbaDestinoResposta;
    private String txCelulaDestinoResposta;
    private Character indAtivo;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUsuarioUltAtualizacao")
    private Usuario usuarioUltAtualizacao;
    private LocalDateTime dtHoraInclusao;
    private LocalDateTime dtHoraUltAtualizacao;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "idPerguntaClonada" ,referencedColumnName = "idConfigPergunta", insertable = true, updatable = true),
        @JoinColumn(name = "idTipoDoctoEntrada", referencedColumnName = "idTipoDoctoEntrada", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    })
    private ConfigPergunta configPerguntaClonada;
    
    private Character indPerguntaSuperAdmin;

Erro :
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'idTipoDoctoEntrada' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.provider.fatoria.model.ConfigPergunta' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 106 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'idTipoDoctoEntrada' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.provider.fatoria.model.ConfigPergunta' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Value.checkColumnDuplication(Value.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.MappingHelper.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(MappingHelper.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:694) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 110 common frames omitted

I expected to be able to run the application and be able to insert and update

Since your primary key is a composite key your foreign key is as well. That, however, means that you need 2 columns for your foreign key but you're trying to reuse idConfigPergunta. Try renaming one of the join columns or making the foreign key join column for document type immutable if you want to use the same type (not sure if this would be supported by Hibernate though).

Did you tried to follow instruction and use @JoinColumn(name = "idTipoDoctoEntrada", referencedColumnName = "idTipoDoctoEntrada", insertable = false, updatable = false)?

@talex moved to Codidact I can't use the configuration @JoinColumn(name = "idTipoDoctoEntrada", referencedColumnName = "idTipoDoctoEntrada", insertable = false, updatable = false), otherwise I won't be able to upsadee and insert, which is what I want to do

Do you want this field to be updated? It is part of primary key? It should be inserted for the same reason. So did you tried it?

I slightly simplified your entity and it works for me
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ConfigPergunta {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ConfigPerguntaPk configPerguntaPk;
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(
        column = @JoinColumn(name = "idPerguntaClonada", referencedColumnName = "idConfigPergunta", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    )
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(
        formula = @JoinFormula(value = "tipo_docto_entrada", referencedColumnName = "tipoDoctoEntrada")
    )
    private ConfigPergunta configPerguntaClonada;

    @Embeddable
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    @ToString
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class ConfigPerguntaPk {
        Long idConfigPergunta;
        String tipoDoctoEntrada;
    }
}

Table definition is:
create table config_pergunta (
   id_config_pergunta bigint not null, 
   id_pergunta_clonada bigint, 
   tipo_docto_entrada varchar(255) not null, 
   primary key (id_config_pergunta, tipo_docto_entrada)
)

